# js->clj (+ including properties from the prototype chain)

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript

I need to convert a JavaScript Object to a Clojure Script Map.

For JS Objects of the prototype `Object` it is `js->clj` that does the job. However if the prototype is a different one, I'm, using the following workaround:

```
(defn jsx->clj [o]
  (reduce (fn [m v] (assoc m (keyword v) (aget o v)))  {} (.keys js/Object o)))
```

This works now for most of the cases. However: Since it uses `Object.keys`, the resulting map only contains the object's own properties.

Now I need to convert all of an object's properties. Meaning including those that come from the prototype chain. In JavaScript this would be done with a `for (.. in ..)` loop.
[see the MDN article for more details on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

How could that be properly translated to ClojureScript?

Or, a more general question, since I'm quite new to ClojureScript: Is it the right way to constantly convert the JavaScript objects to Clojure stuctures? Of course I do that because of a better integration to the clojure universe. And simply I find it annoying to "mess around" with aget and aset all the time. On the other hand I must say that I observe myself spending a lot of time with these casting issues. Well, I guess it's not an easy question, performance plays a huge role as well here. Anyway, just in case someone has some "paths" for me here...

Comment: Can I ask why you need to copy the object, prototype chain and all? Perhaps your problem could be addressed by reframing the question.